# Excel - Finding and Allocating

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to find the same values in column A (e.g. column A can contain buy a dog, white dog, cute cats, cuddly cats - I would need find all "cats" and then assign them to certain categories, e.g. "CAT Lover" which would then be a category and be pasted in a column next to all the cat related values).

Thank you
Erika

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** enter:

```
=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"cats",""))=LEN(A1),"","CAT Lover")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Erika,

an alternative way to do this (by hand, but more easy when you want to avoid formulas) is:

Mark the first row (where the column headlines are)

Click on the Data tab

Select "Filter"

Now you will see a filter appear next to every column headline. You can select the small triangle next to the column headline, select "Text Filters", and then choose "contains...". 
Enter "cat" (without the "") here and you will only see columns that contain the word cat. You can now simply copy the "CAT lover" to all cells in column B.

When you are done, simply select "Clear filter" in the Data tab up on top!